# How do I compile my 16 bit Mac assembly code?

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, 16-bit

So I'm trying to assemble this piece of 16bit assembly code on my Mac (Monterey):

```
    global _main

    section     .text

_main:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, '!'
    int 0x10

    mov  ah, 0x4c
    int  0x21
```

I am using the NASM assembler, and have so far managed to get it assembled into a .com file using the following command:

`nasm testing.asm -o test.com -f bin`

However when trying to link this into an executable using LD with the following command:

`ld -e _main -static -o test test.com -arch x86_64`

it comes up with the error:

> ````
> standing-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for
> unknown-unsupported file format ( 0xB4 0x0E 0xB0 0x21 0xCD 0x10 0xB7
> 0x0E 0xB5 0x0E 0xB6 0x0E 0xBE 0x0E 0x00 0xBF ) Undefined symbols for
> architecture x86_64:   "_main", referenced from:
>      -u command line option ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 ```
> ````

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're writing a program for an old PC DOS/BIOS system. Such programs won't work even on  a Windows PC without an emulator.

Comment: Why are you trying to link 16 bit code into a 64 bit executable?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So I was originally trying to use 64 bit to draw pixels, however switched to 16 bit because interrupts don't seem to work on 64 bit.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Why do you use assembler for something that would be trivial in a high-level language?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Drawing pixels anywhere on the screen is really more trivial in 16-bit DOS.

Comment: I'm doing it in such a low level language because I want to try and make a game as low level as possible. (because why not)

Comment: @FonkinStubbleduck If you want to develop a DOS game that can only run on an emulator like Dosbox, all of your other code should follow, even the standard C library, for example. Or there is always some API to draw a pixel on the screen specific to your system, which you can call in assembly.

Comment: And of course, if you're using a DOS emulator, you cannot communicate with your system API.

Comment: *(because why not)* - Because modern graphics APIs are exposed via user-space libraries, not just raw system calls.  Even if you used MacOS system calls instead of DOS, it would be a *lot* harder in asm to get things drawn manually.  And asking the OS to draw each pixel separately isn't an efficient model.  So if you want your game to be slow and require way more work to write, and maybe not be portable to different versions of the same OS (if the actual `syscall` interface of sending data to a graphics server changes, since you're duplicating some user-space libraries), then go ahead.

Comment: But writing asm that no version of MacOS has ever supported isn't a good start.  x86 MacOS didn't build on top of any of the IBM-PC BIOS / DOS legacy even for booting; it *just* used x86 CPUs with its own firmware.  (It does actually use EFI for booting, so not totally Apple-specific.)  Current versions of MacOS don't even support running 32-bit x86 code, only 64-bit.  No versions have ever supported 16-bit mode.  (Even m68k wasn't really 16-bit, but I thought that with classic MacOS was what this question would be about based on the title!  I was very surprised to see x86 BIOS calls)

Comment: @PeterCordes "asking the OS to draw each pixel separately isn't an efficient model" - You can draw each pixel on a buffer and ask the system to copy the whole buffer to show on the screen each frame. This way is actually fast enough for most 2D games, and more portable than using hardware graphics. Some SSE optimization (SSE2 is enough) can make it much faster.

Comment: @xiver77: Yes, exactly.  That's what I had in mind if someone wants to write drawing functions in assembly; draw into a local buffer and use a graphics library function call to copy that to the screen. (Probably from C or C++; probably a big pain to deal with types and constants defined in headers from asm.)  Modern computers have lots of bandwidth for copying to video memory, compared to the latency for individual operations.  (Especially with a discrete GPU over actual PCIe.)

Comment: I want to make sure you understand the fundamental problem here.  `int 0x21` is a call into MS-DOS, and `int 0x10` is a call into a PC BIOS.  Your Mac has neither a PC BIOS nor a copy of MS-DOS, and never has.  You need to use the APIs for the operating system you have.  Note that your code won't even work on Windows today; 64-bit WIndows no longer supports 16-bit apps.